# Creating new rows in dataframe based on string values in multiple columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I ran into this problem where I have a dataframe that looks like the following (the values in the last 3 columns are usually 4-5 alphanumeric codes).

```
import pandas as pd

data = {'ID':['P39','S32'],
        'Name':['Pipe','Screw'],
        'Col3':['Test1, Test2, Test3','Test6, Test7'],
        'Col4':['','Test8, Test9'],
        'Col5':['Test4, Test5','Test10, Test11, Test12, Test13']
       }

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

|  | ID | Name | Col3 | Col4 | Col5 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | P39 | Pipe | Test1, Test2, Test3 |  | Test4, Test5 |
| 1 | S32 | Screw | Test6, Test7 | Test8, Test9 | Test10, Test11, Test12, Test13 |

I want to expand this dataframe or create a new one based on the values in the last 3 columns in each row. I want to create more rows based on the maximum amount of values separated by commas in one of the last 3 rows. I then want to keep the first 2 columns the same in all of the expanded rows. But I want to fill the last 3 columns in the expanded rows with only one value each from the original column.

In the above example, the first row would indicate I need 3 total rows (Col3 has the most at 3 values), and the second row would indicate I need 4 total rows (Col5 has the most at 4 values). A desired output would be along the lines of:

|  | ID | Name | Col3 | Col4 | Col5 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | P39 | Pipe | Test1 |  | Test4 |
| 1 | P39 | Pipe | Test2 |  | Test5 |
| 2 | P39 | Pipe | Test3 |  |  |
| 3 | S32 | Screw | Test6 | Test8 | Test10 |
| 4 | S32 | Screw | Test7 | Test9 | Test11 |
| 5 | S32 | Screw |  |  | Test12 |
| 6 | S32 | Screw |  |  | Test13 |

I first found a way to figure out the number of rows needed. I also had the idea to append the values to a new dataframe in the same loop. Although, I'm not sure how to separate the values in the last 3 columns and append them one by one in the rows. I know the str.split() is useful to put the values into a list. My only idea would be if I need to loop through each column separately and append it to the correct row, but I'm not sure how to do that.

```
output1 = pd.DataFrame(
    columns = ['ID', 'Name', 'Col3', 'Col4', 'Col5'])

for index, row in df.iterrows():
    
    output2 = pd.DataFrame(
        columns = ['ID', 'Name', 'Col3', 'Col4', 'Col5'])

    col3counter = df.iloc[index, 2].count(',')
    col4counter = df.iloc[index, 3].count(',')
    col5counter = df.iloc[index, 4].count(',')
    
    numofnewcols = max(col3counter, col4counter, col5counter) + 1

    iter1 = df.iloc[index, 2].split(', ')
    iter2 = df.iloc[index, 3].split(', ')
    iter3 = df.iloc[index, 4].split(', ')

    #for q in iter1
        #output2.iloc[ , 2] = 
    

    output1 = pd.concat([output1, output2], ignore_index=True)
    del output2
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A bit tricky but it should work with `melt` to flat your dataframe then `pivot_table` to reshape it:

```
out = (df.reset_index().melt(['ID', 'Name', 'index'], var_name='col', value_name='val')
         .assign(val=lambda x: x['val'].str.split(', ')).explode('val')
         .assign(row=lambda x: x.groupby(['index', 'col']).cumcount())
         .pivot_table('val', ['index', 'row', 'ID', 'Name'], 'col', aggfunc='first')
         .droplevel(['index', 'row']).reset_index().rename_axis(columns=None).fillna(''))
```

Output:

|  | ID | Name | Col3 | Col4 | Col5 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | P39 | Pipe | Test1 |  | Test4 |
| 1 | P39 | Pipe | Test2 |  | Test5 |
| 2 | P39 | Pipe | Test3 |  |  |
| 3 | S32 | Screw | Test6 | Test8 | Test10 |
| 4 | S32 | Screw | Test7 | Test9 | Test11 |
| 5 | S32 | Screw |  |  | Test12 |
| 6 | S32 | Screw |  |  | Test13 |

Answer (score 2):

Here is a way:

```
cols = ['Col3','Col4','Col5']

s = df[cols].stack().str.split(', ')
s2 = s.str.len().groupby(level=0).transform(lambda x: x.max() - x)
df.loc[:,~df.columns.isin(cols)].join((s + s2.map(lambda x: x * [''])).unstack()).explode(cols).reset_index(drop=True)
```

Here is another way using `.stack()` `str.split()` and creating a new `df` using the output:

```
cols = ['Col3','Col4','Col5']

s = df[cols].stack().str.split(',')
(df[['ID','Name']].join(pd.DataFrame(s.tolist(),index = s.index)
.stack()
.unstack(level=1)
.droplevel(1)
.fillna('')))
```

Output:

```
    ID   Name   Col3   Col4    Col5
0  P39   Pipe  Test1          Test4
1  P39   Pipe  Test2          Test5
2  P39   Pipe  Test3               
3  S32  Screw  Test6  Test8  Test10
4  S32  Screw  Test7  Test9  Test11
5  S32  Screw                Test12
6  S32  Screw                Test13
```

Answer (score 1):

This equalizes the number of values in each list by row, so that you can get your desired output with a multi-column explode.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

cols = ['Col3','Col4','Col5']

for col in cols:
     df[col] = df[col].str.split(', ')

df['rows'] = df[cols].applymap(len).max(axis=1)

for col in cols:
    df[col] = df[[col, 'rows']].apply(lambda x: x[col] + [np.nan]*(x['rows'] - len(x[col])), axis=1)
'''
# Or, simplified with more-itertools and np.vectorize
from more_itertools import padded
vec_pad = np.vectorize(padded, excluded={1})
for col in cols:
    df[col] = vec_pad(df[col], np.nan, df.rows)
df[cols] = df[cols].applymap(list)
'''
df = (df.explode(cols)
        .drop('rows', axis=1)
        .replace('', np.nan))
print(df)
```

Output:

```
    ID   Name   Col3   Col4    Col5
0  P39   Pipe  Test1    NaN   Test4
0  P39   Pipe  Test2    NaN   Test5
0  P39   Pipe  Test3    NaN     NaN
1  S32  Screw  Test6  Test8  Test10
1  S32  Screw  Test7  Test9  Test11
1  S32  Screw    NaN    NaN  Test12
1  S32  Screw    NaN    NaN  Test13
```