# Expand two columns that do not have matching elements

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe with column A and column B having some values separated by comma. I would like to expand these two together to get a row with all other information and one element per row from A and B.

I have tried to use expand but it does not work as I do not have all my variables in column A and B equal. For 2 elements in A I don't always have 2 elements in B.

Example of dataset:

```
data = {'col1': [1, 2, 3, 4], 'col2': [5, 6, 7, "NaN"], 'A': ["event", "event2, NaN", "event3, event4", "event5, event6"], 'B': ["01-05-2022", "02-05-2022, 03-05-2022", "04-05-2022", ""]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=data)
df
```

| col1 | col2 | A | B |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 5 | event | 01-05-2022 |
| 2 | 6 | event2 | 02-05-2022, 03-05-2022 |
| 3 | 7 | event3, event4 | 04-05-2022 |
| 4 | NaN | event5, event6 |  |

I would like to get something that looks like this:

```
data = {'col1': [1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4], 'col2': [5, 6, 6, 7, 7, "NaN", "NaN"], 'A': ["event", "event2", "NaN", "event3", "event4", "event5", "event6"], 'B': ["01-05-2022", "02-05-2022", "03-05-2022", "04-05-2022", "04-05-2022", "", ""]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=data)
df
```

| col1 | col2 | A | B |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 5 | event | 01-05-2022 |
| 2 | 6 | event2 | 02-05-2022 |
| 2 | 6 | NaN | 03-05-2022 |
| 3 | 7 | event3 | 04-05-2022 |
| 3 | 7 | event4 | 04-05-2022 |
| 4 | NaN | event5 |  |
| 4 | NaN | event6 |  |

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Creating new rows in dataframe based on string values in multiple columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72924307/creating-new-rows-in-dataframe-based-on-string-values-in-multiple-columns)

Comment: Only partially. I was able to use that example but I have an extra caveat. If I have multiple values in col A and just one in col B I should get the value in col B for every value in col A.  The solutions presented in the example you forwarded gives the value in B only to the first value in A and leaves the rest blank. hope this makes sense

Answer (score 0):

With the dataframe you provided, here is one way to do it:

```py
df = (
    df
    .assign(
        A=df["A"].apply(lambda x: x.split(", ")),
        B=df["B"].apply(lambda x: x.split(", ")),
    )
    .explode("A")
    .explode("B")
    .pipe(
        lambda df_: df_.replace("NaN", pd.NA)
        .dropna(subset="A", how="any")
        .reset_index(drop=True)
    )
)
```

```py
print(df)
# Output
   col1  col2       A           B
0     1     5   event  01-05-2022
1     2     6  event2  02-05-2022
2     2     6  event2  03-05-2022
3     3     7  event3  04-05-2022
4     3     7  event4  04-05-2022
5     4  <NA>  event5
6     4  <NA>  event6
```